# PhalconPHP select_box - How to use join data as option label?

Tags: php, mysql, join, phalcon

I have two tables; Pages and PagesTranslation which are joined. I can get all the data and translations; For example on single page I can get title via `{ page.pagestranslation.getTitle() }}`

Now, I am listing all the pages in my controller:

```
    $pages = Pages::find();
    $this->view->pages = $pages;
```

And I want to use it in the select:

```
{{ select("parent_page", pages, 'using': ['id', 'title']) }}
```

The ID get's populated, but I can't find a way to get title from the pages.pagestranslation to the option label in the select. How can I use joined data values in the select box ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there's not an out of box solution for this at the moment, but hopefully there's an easy workaround...

In your `Pages` model add an property that hooks the title:

```
class Pages extends \Phalcon\Mvc\Model
{
  public function afterFetch()
  {
     $this->title = $this->pagestranslation->getTitle();
  }
}
```

Then in Volt nothing changes:

```
{{ select("parent_page", pages, 'using': ['id', 'title']) }}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Worked like a charm!